# Multiple Media Web parts for Videos in a list?

Tags: web-part, spgridview, gridview, media-streaming

I want to create a video library for users to upload videos. These should be displayed with a Media Web Part.

I would like to be able to have on web part for each video so it becomes a list like so:

```
1. Title1    (Length1)
   [Video1] <-- media web part to play the video
--------------------
2. Title2    (Length2)
   [Video2]
--------------------
...
```

Can I achieve this with an `SPGridView` and embed multiple media web parts? Will I have to create custom controls for this? Just give me some ideas how I could provide preview functionality for each item in the list.

---

**EDIT:** Video is just an example here. In the end I want to fully use the media web part so there will be videos + audio in the list, both of which the media webpart is able to play. PDFs which cannot be rendered by it will just be displayed as regular links.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes into my mind is to create a custom list schema which includes the appropriate CAML to render the video file as HTML5 video tag.

This would of course require that you either use a modern Web browser (e.g. IE9 or the latest version of Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera) or employ a technique described at the "video for everbody" page http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody.

Another option is to embed a video player into the list CAML like JWPlayer which is not free for commercial use, but is getting good reviews (note that I'm not affiliated with the company producing it). This would make it browser independent and even work in old IE 8 and below.

Comment: Long story short: Video is just an example. The media player webpart can play videos as well as audio. There will also be audio files. I don't want to implement a switcher - depending on the type of file load a video tag, load an audio tag etc. Secondly I can't be sure of the modernness of the browser. Lastly: My question really is specific on the Media web part. PS: You surely didn't mean *"CAML to render the video file"*, but *"XSLT"* right? CAML only queries some data source.

Comment: I meant a CAML schema used to render the HTML. But if you want to render audio or video browser independent then I'd go with a player like JWPlayer and embed it into the view schema.